# Function BirthDay in Angular JS Code is not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

When I click on the button with the function `add()` there is a bug !
this function must render a list and extract the persons who's
birthday is today but what happens is a refrech of the page. Can
anyone help me please.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >

var app = angular.module('app.demo', []);

app.controller('LancerEvalController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.obj = {
  dateBirth: "",
  nom: "",
  mail: ""
};

$scope.add = function() {

  $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://...../_api/web/lists/getByTitle('anniversaire2')/items?$select=dateBirth,nom,mail&$top=1000",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
    }

  ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.obj = data.d.results;
    var d = new Date();

    var n = d.getDay();
    console.log("n = ", n);
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    console.log("y = ", y);
    var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
    console.log("m = ", m);


    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.obj.length; i++) {

      var b = new Date($scope.obj[i].dateBirth);

      var nom = $scope.obj[i].nom;

      var mail = $scope.obj[i].mail;

      var nb = b.getDay();
      var dateBirth = $scope.obj[i].dateBirth;

      //var mb = b.getMonth()+1;
      if (d.getDate() == b.getDate() && d.getMonth() + 1 == b.getMonth() + 1) {
        console.log("nb = ", nb);
        console.log("b = ", b);
        var n = d.getDay();
        console.log("n = ", n);
        myFunction(n, nom, mail, dateBirth);
      } else if (d.getDate() + 1 == b.getDate() && d.getMonth() + 1 == b.getMonth() + 1) {
        console.log("nb = ", nb);
        console.log("b = ", b);
        var n = d.getDay();
        var n = n + 1;
        console.log("n+1 = ", n);
        myFunction(n, nom, mail, dateBirth);
      }

      function myFunction(n, nom, mail, dateBirth) {

        //  alert($scope.month.title);
        // console.log($scope.month);
        $scope.dateBirthD = dateBirth;
        $scope.counter = n;
        $scope.email = mail;
        $scope.loginNName = nom;
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Birthdays');
        // create the ListItemInformational object  
        var listItemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        // add the item to the list  
        var listItem = list.addItem(listItemInfo);
        // Assign Values for fields  
        listItem.set_item('DisplayName', $scope.loginNName);
        listItem.set_item('Email', $scope.email);
        listItem.set_item('BirthDayOfYear', $scope.counter);
        listItem.set_item('dateBirth', $scope.dateBirthD);
        listItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
          Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
          Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
        );

      };
      onQuerySucceeded = function() {
        //alert('votre message a été envoyé avec succès');
        console.log("votre message a été envoyé avec succès ");
      }

      onQueryFailed = function(sender, args) {
        // alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
      }
    }



  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
  });

</script>
```

```html
<div ng-app="app.demo">
  <div ng-controller="LancerEvalController">

    <button ng-click="add()">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to produce a [mcve] to boost your chances of getting an answer.